# Query non repeated values for a column with other columns using analytic functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g Release 1.
Following up on [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365678/oracle-query-for-finding-non-repeated-rows).

Having this set of rows:

```
Name     Contact_No

A        123
A        124
B        125
C        126
C        127
```

I would like to return this using analytic functions:

```
Name     Contact_No
B        125
```

I could do this

```
select name, Contact_No
from   tbl_name
where  name in ( SELECT name
                 FROM   tbl_name
                 GROUP  BY name
                 HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
                )
```

or this

```
SELECT name, max(Contact_No)
FROM   tbl_name
GROUP  BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
```

But I want a solution where I can avoid the subquery or joining the table with itself or using min/max which could confuse anyone who reads the code!
I believe this is possible with analytic functions but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you need to use analytic functions; if you want to return the entire row. Judging by your current query an analytic [`COUNT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions039.htm#SQLRF00624).

```
select *
  from ( select a.*, count(*) over ( partition by name ) as ct
           from tbl_name )
 where ct = 1
```

To explain, the partition by is, effectively, the same as a GROUP BY, except without doing one. This counts the number of records *per* name and returns that in-line, no matter the number of records with that name. You can then restrict on this generated column.

Although this does use a sub-query there's nothing intrinsically wrong with this method. You only scan the table/index once; unlike in your current example where you scan it twice.

I would normally recommend that you have an index on `NAME` here, but it does depend on your specific circumstances. You may need to scan the full table, in which case an index will not help you.

Furthermore, if you *only* have these two columns there's no point in an analytic query. You can use your second option to obtain the same result.

```
SELECT name, max(Contact_No)
  FROM tbl_name
 GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
```

Analytic queries are useful when there's additional columns you need to return, which you can't include in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben. I thought we could do that without a subquery.

Comment: As I say in my answer there's nothing wrong with sub-queries. You want to minimise the number of tables/indexes you access.